# submit parameters from form input range only if chosen by user

Tags: html, forms, input, range, get-request

how can I achieve that the parameters from the input elements range, are only submitted via GET-Request if the user interacts with the range slider before submitting. So that when the form is submitted the default values are not always submitted?

```html
<div data-role="rangeslider">
  <label for="range-1a">Rangeslider:</label>
  <input type="range" name="absMin" id="rangeMin" min="0" max="1" value="0" step="0.1">
  <label for="range-1b">Rangeslider:</label>
  <input type="range" name="absMax" id="rangeMax" min="0" max="1" value="1" step="0.1">
</div>
```

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Where is the code for the action you want to achieve, post what you have.

Answer (score 0):

there're many ways to do that, maybe the easiest way is changing your slider's initial value to -1, but why you do that? what if your user actually want to choose but they don't do the slide because they feel like the slider already showed the value they wanted?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).